# No p gain specified for pid

Tags: ros, gazebo-simu

I tried launching my robot in the `Gazebo` world and I could see my robot arm, but could not find the end effector, and when I try to click on any plugin Gazebo closes off suddenly!

People told me to add a `.yml` file. And but the robot works fine on the `RViz` platform

```yaml
gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains:
    shoulder_pan_joint: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
    shoulder_lift_joint: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
    elbow_joint: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
    wrist_1_joint: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
    wrist_2_joint: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
    wrist_3_joint: {p: 100.0, i: 0.01, d: 10.0}
```

and I added the above,

```
[controller_spawner-4] process has died [pid 18617, exit code 2, cmd /opt/ros/melodic/lib/controller_manager/spawner __name:=controller_spawner __log:=/home/akash/.ros/log/7a4b985a-ea0b-11eb-a6b5-7c67a2e59a25/controller_spawner-4.log].
log file: /home/akash/.ros/log/7a4b985a-ea0b-11eb-a6b5-7c67a2e59a25/controller_spawner-4*.log
[ INFO] [1626867488.573071456]: Finished loading Gazebo ROS API Plugin.
[ INFO] [1626867488.579089609]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo_gui/set_physics_properties] has not been advertised, waiting...
[ INFO] [1626867488.836513846]: waitForService: Service [/gazebo/set_physics_properties] is now available.
[ INFO] [1626867488.890592907, 0.020000000]: Physics dynamic reconfigure ready.
[INFO] [1626867489.039121, 0.000000]: Loading model XML from ros parameter robot_description
[INFO] [1626867489.056799, 0.000000]: Waiting for service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [1626867489.064258, 0.186000]: Calling service /gazebo/spawn_urdf_model
[INFO] [1626867489.366671, 0.325000]: Spawn status: SpawnModel: Successfully spawned entity
[ INFO] [1626867489.615558431, 0.325000000]: Camera Plugin: Using the 'robotNamespace' param: '/'
[ INFO] [1626867489.619115323, 0.325000000]: Camera Plugin (ns = /)  <tf_prefix_>, set to ""
[spawn_gazebo_model-3] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/akash/.ros/log/7a4b985a-ea0b-11eb-a6b5-7c67a2e59a25/spawn_gazebo_model-3*.log
[ INFO] [1626867489.736882435, 0.325000000]: Loading gazebo_ros_control plugin
[ INFO] [1626867489.737195933, 0.325000000]: Starting gazebo_ros_control plugin in namespace: /
[ INFO] [1626867489.738163986, 0.325000000]: gazebo_ros_control plugin is waiting for model URDF in parameter [robot_description] on the ROS param server.
[ WARN] [1626867489.860372812, 0.325000000]: Deprecated syntax, please prepend 'hardware_interface/' to 'PositionJointInterface' within the <hardwareInterface> tag in joint 'shoulder_1_joint'.
[ERROR] [1626867489.862396772, 0.325000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/shoulder_1_joint
[ WARN] [1626867489.862942465, 0.325000000]: Deprecated syntax, please prepend 'hardware_interface/' to 'PositionJointInterface' within the <hardwareInterface> tag in joint 'shoulder_2_joint'.
[ERROR] [1626867489.867874675, 0.325000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/shoulder_2_joint
[ WARN] [1626867489.867934525, 0.325000000]: Deprecated syntax, please prepend 'hardware_interface/' to 'PositionJointInterface' within the <hardwareInterface> tag in joint 'elbow_1_joint'.
[ERROR] [1626867489.868804177, 0.325000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/elbow_1_joint
[ WARN] [1626867489.868847889, 0.325000000]: Deprecated syntax, please prepend 'hardware_interface/' to 'PositionJointInterface' within the <hardwareInterface> tag in joint 'wrist_1_joint'.
[ERROR] [1626867489.869519502, 0.325000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_1_joint
[ WARN] [1626867489.869559452, 0.325000000]: Deprecated syntax, please prepend 'hardware_interface/' to 'PositionJointInterface' within the <hardwareInterface> tag in joint 'wrist_2_joint'.
[ERROR] [1626867489.870294428, 0.325000000]: No p gain specified for pid.  Namespace: /gazebo_ros_control/pid_gains/wrist_2_joint
[ WARN] [1626867489.870363581, 0.325000000]: Deprecated syntax, please prepend 'hardware_interface/' to 'PositionJointInterface' within the <hardwareInterface> tag in joint 'wrist_3_joint'.
[ERROR] [1626867489.871283295, 0.325000000]: No p gain ...
```

Comment: Rviz is merely a viewer; it just reports what is loaded by default from the robot_param (if setup), and the messages you subscribe to. It's not running or simulating anything. It is probably broken in gazebo because your configuration is broken; since your controller_spawner died, check the causes, such as an incorrectly formatted file.

Comment: @Akash firstly please provide more details on your problem, the `roslaunch` file used and all configuration files used, the **full output** of the `roslaunch` and not just partial one as you did here, and furthermore please be specific about your problem: **PID Gains**, or **End-Effector Parsing** or **Gazebo plugin crash**!